# In sheets, duplicating responses into specific tab(s)

Tags: date, google-sheets, tabs, duplicates

In forms collection, users provide me data. Most importantly in the data given is the date(s) they select (or sign up for, in my instance). I've created new tabs in the spreadsheet that are associated with the dates. I'm copying and pasting the exact information that they provide into the correct date(s) tab. Sometimes they select multiple dates. However, at this rate, I'm moving so slow and making many mistakes.

Is there a code that can duplicate what I'm doing to avoid the simple mistakes I'm making and save time?

Updated: here is the link to a mock sheet (I hope I did it right): [Mock Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XMoLMQKSvnfIIUWgCESgVjtqMzrYz1sQp25BttjV90M/edit?usp=sharing)

(quick pic of what I'm working with)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMOmR.jpg

Comment: A picture is not very helpful. I make this comparison often, but it's like showing us a close-up of an inch of fur and then expecting that we'll correctly guess the animal. I invite you to share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it where you've sanitized any personal data, if that is applicable to your situation). Then we can see the entire setup. I don't recommend setting up a separate sheet for each date unless you will be adding more data to each line item in that separate sheet. If you are just needing to *view* data for a date, there are other more efficient ways.

Comment: Gotcha. I updated with the link. Thank you.

Comment: And, yes, I need to edit each tab individually and add info/adjust that wouldn't/ isn't meant to replicate on the other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your spreadsheet. Here is what I recommend:

1.) In your existing individual date sheets, select and delete whichever columns you will not be using; likewise, select and delete all rows beyond the maximum number of rows you might ever need per sheet. Keeping sheets trim is the professional standard, makes it easier to focus on the important information, and assures maximum processing speed.

2.) Delete *everything* from your existing individual date sheets, including the headers.

3.) Place the following formula into cell A1 of each sheet:

`=FILTER({Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!F:F},(ROW(Sheet1!A:A)=1)+(REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!E:E,"December 17, 2021")))`

Adjust the date in quotation marks to match the sheet. It seems that all of your events may be happening from 5:00 - 9:00, so you don't need to include that if my assumption is correct. However, if there are different times on the same day (and will therefore be two different sheets for that day), you will need to include the start time in the formula's quotes as well, exactly as it will come in from the form (e.g., "December 17, 2021 Friday, 5:00pm"). The hyphen and end time seems it would be superfluous and can be left off.

4.) To create a new individual date sheet, simply duplicate an existing individual date sheet, rename the copy, color your header row as desired, and change the formula section between those quotes in the A1 formula (which will already be in place from the duplicate sheet.

5.) Since you will be adding further notes or other information in additional columns within each individual date sheet, be sure that you never delete information from Sheet1; otherwise, the formula-produces row information will collapse to eliminate deleted rows, and your manually entered data will not match up. For this reason, I recommend simply `Hide`-ing Sheet1 entirely, as this will cut down on the chance that someone may accidentally tamper with the data coming into that sheet. There is not reason to have Sheet1 showing, since all data will be included in some other sheet due to the formulas there.

The formula `FILTER`s in only the five target columns, which are included in the opening virtual array formed between the curly brackets `{ }`; and it will include rows that match either one of two conditions (shown between sets of parentheses, where the plus symbol means 'OR'): either A.) the row is Row 1 (i.e., the header row information) or B.) the part in quotes can be found in `Sheet1!E:E`.